# LCD TFT Display - MIO283QT-11 and ILI9341 controller - displaying a character

Tags: c, lcd

If anyone worked with MIO283QT-11 LCD Display with ILI9341 Display controller, please let me knoe.

I am writing C code that helps display a character on the screen.
The screen is 320 by 240 pixel matrix. The controller provides a GRAM(Graphics RAM) memory where in we write the data to display corresponding character.

For character A, the data that is to be sent to GRAM is:

//--  character:  A
//--  font matrix£ºwidth x height=8x16
0x00,0x00,0x00,0x10,0x10,0x18,0x28,0x28,0x24,0x3C,0x44,0x42,0x42,0xE7,0x00,0x00

I have done initializing of LCD by sending sequence of commands and command parameters. I have done the initializing in a function called void ili9341();

Should I just send this data for character A ? Should I be giving the location on the screen where the character is to be displayed? How should I give location and how should I send the data?

Comment: Did you read the datasheet or document of the library you use?

Comment: Yes, I read the datasheet. I did not find much info. on how to display

Comment: If I remember correctly there is a maker / electronic engineering / raspberry community on SE, perhaps it is a good idea to ask there